# What is the etymological origin of the word キノピオ (Toad in Super Mario Bros)?

Tags: etymology, katakana, loanwords, video-games

I just found out the Toad character from the Super Mario Bros is known as キノピオ in Japan.

Where does that name come from? I know 茸 (きのこ) means mushroom, but what does the suffix -ピオ stand for?

Thanks in advance.

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%8E%E3%83%94%E3%82%AA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you search for the page referenced on Wikipedia ("11 Origins of 11 Super Mario Characters' Names"), you'll find the answer:

> Anyway, in Japan, he’s named Kinopio, which is a mixture of the word for mushroom (“kinoko”) and the Japanese version of Pinocchio (“pinokio”). Those blend to be something along the lines of “A Real Mushroom Boy.”

https://11points.com/11-origins-11-super-mario-characters-names/

Comment: Could you specify which page you cited?

Comment: Updated my answer.